# Few unusual C/C++ declarations

Tags: c, enum, struct

I came across this Enum and Struct declarations in a project supposedly done by an expert.
The declarations / definitions are little different than what im used to so far.

```
enum EnumKeys {
  KEY_MENU ,
  KEY_EXIT ,
  KEY_DOWN ,
  KEY_UP  ,
  KEY_RIGHT ,
.
.
.

};
```

But nowhere in the code the actual Enum had been defined by a line of code like

```
 EnumKeys test;
```

for example. But still the KEY_MENU, KEY_EXIT are freely available just after this declaration. For example, if I type `cout << KEY_EXIT`, it prints 1.

Other instance is, this structure declaration / definition.

```
typedef struct t_ExpoData {
  int8_t  expNorm;
  int8_t  expDr;
  int8_t  drSw;
}ExpoData;

typedef struct t_ModelData {
  ...
  ...
  ExpoData  expoData[4]; // 3*4
}ModelData;
```

So the way I read this is, there is a new structure with the name ExpoData and one instance of it is ExpoData. 
Instead of using that instance right away, why the second declaration ExpoData  `expoData[4]` ?

If anyone understands this, as of what clang specification is this, and how to interpret this correctly, that is much appreciated.

Comment: Looks off-topic to me. SO?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But nowhere in the code the actual Enum had been defined by something like EnumKeys test;

For the enumeration, there may never be any declaration of a variable of that type, but it may be used for creating other values. Often in C, `enum` types are combined into `int`s or `long`s. For example, a developer could write:

```
int bitmask = KEY_UP | KEY_DOWN;
```

and then use that value in a comparison to check whether the up or down arrow key was pressed.

> So the way I read this is, there is a new structure with the name ExpoData and one instance of it is ExpoData.

No, that's not what this means. The `typedef` in this style:

```
typedef struct <someName> {
    ... fields
} <somePossiblyOtherName>;
```

is a typical C type definition. They take the form:

```
typedef <existing type> <new type>;
```

Furthermore, C `struct` definitions can be done without the typedef like this:

```
struct <typeName> {
    ...fields
};
```

You can then use that type by typing `struct <typeName>` before a variable declaration, function return type or function argument. Like this:

```
struct <typeName> functionName(struct <typeName> argument)
```

where *typeName* is the name of the type.

So what the type definition in your code is saying is that they are declaring a new type that is a `struct t_ExpoData` and they are giving the new type the name `ExpoData`. It saves users of the type from having to type `struct t_ExpoData` every time they want to use it. Instead they can type just `ExpoData`. It could have been written as 2 different  lines like this:

```
struct t_ExpoData {
    ... fields...
};
typedef struct t_ExpoData ExpoData;
```

> Instead of using that instance right away, why the second declaration ExpoData expoData[4] ?

The author of the code is saying that they want an array of 4 instances of `ExpoData` in their `ModelData` structure, and they want that field to be called `expoData`. You would access it like this:

```
ModelData someModel;
someModel.expoData[0].expNorm = 5;
```

Comment: "They take the form: `typedef <existing type> <new type>;`" - that's true for some types, but not all.  Typedefs can get every bit as complex as any declaration: `typedef int (*foo(void))[10];` creates a typedef named `foo` which is an alias for "function returning pointer to 10-element array of `int`".  C declaration syntax is fairly complex, meaning typedefs can get pretty complex as well.